# IPython3 on SL (RHEL)

Tags: python-3.x, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I am running IPython (and especially a notebook server) on Scientific Linux 6.3 (thus RHEL). I tried to use python3 to run setup and use ipython and also the ipython3 command. However this fails all the time. Before I go into detail with error messages and such - I read somewhere that IPython3 is currently not supported for RHEL derivates (I think the post was relating to Fedora), is this true?

Cheers

Phil

Comment: IPython should run on any Python 3.2 or above (probably 3.1 as well, but we don't test that). I'm not aware of any problems with redhat based systems.

Comment: It works fine for me on FC18. Please post details if you want to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 3):

I understand that this is a fairly old question. However, given that **Fedora 20** (the current version) comes with IPython 0.13 which lacks some functionality of IPython 2, I decided to write down how I installed it, in hopes that someone might find it useful. My focus was on the newest version of IPython Notebook.

---

**Edit:** I was just made aware of [this IPython backport repo](http://copr.fedoraproject.org/coprs/tomspur/ipython/).

---

All `yum` and `pip*` commands here are to be run as the root. Those disliking such approach can prepend `sudo` do all `yum` and `pip*` commands and run the rest of them without `sudo`.

Remove RPMs of IPython (to avoid collisions):

```
yum remove python-ipython\* python3-ipython\*
```

Install `pip`:

```
yum install python-pip python3-pip
```

Install additional Python dependencies (it did work for me without these, but I didn't test much, so something might break down without these):

```
yum install python-jinja2 python-markupsafe python3-jinja2 python3-markupsafe python-devel python3-devel
```

Install IPython for both Python 2 and Python 3:

```
pip install ipython[all]
pip-python3 install ipython[all]
```

I've read somewhere that on Ubuntu, `pip-python3` is called `pip3`.

To run IPython Notebook for Python 2 (do this as an ordinary user, not the root):

```
ipython notebook
```

To run IPython Notebook for Python 3 (do this as an ordinary user, not the root):

```
ipython3 notebook
```

To test your installation, call `iptest` or `iptest3` (again, as an ordinary user, not the root). These tests may fail, so you might need additional packages for them to pass. For me, `PyZMQ` failed. This was fixed by installing two more packages:

```
yum install python-zmq-tests python3-zmq-tests
```

Many thanks to IPython-dev mailing list members Zoltán Vörös, for pointing me in the right direction, and Roberto Colistete Jr., for additional Python dependencies.